# Set up HTTPPOST android?

Tags: java, android

I want to set up httppost to my server.
For now I have address for emulator, but now I want to test app online.
Here is the code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/posloviPodaci/index.php");
```

How to set up address for my server, which I have online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you only need to change `"http://10.0.2.2/posloviPodaci/index.php"` to something like `"http://your-site-name/posloviPodaci/index.php"` or depending on how you host the **index.php** on server.

Comment: you need to pass all together with http and www (if any) as url. for e.g. `http://www.site.com/posloviPodaci/index.php`. Also make sure if you need to use **http** or **https** depending on your server's configuration

Comment: Yes, I solved, it shows me error because my server cPanel was on.
And after I turned it off app start to work normal.
Thanks,
Wolf.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I may be misunderstanding the problem, but don't you just need to change the URL passed into the HttpPost object so that it points to your server?